# Rails upsert return value won't work to create instance | ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, upsert

Attempting to use fetch with Rails to save form data to a Postgre DB, I am being thrown one cryptic error after the next and I am perfectly out of my depth on how to resolve this. All I am trying to do is taking input values and saving them to two different tables.

The server throws the following at me:

```
  Tag Upsert (4.7ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("category","name") VALUES ('topic', 'abc') ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "category"=excluded."category","name"=excluded."name" RETURNING "id"
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:36:in `block in create'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 180ms (ActiveRecord: 54.1ms | Allocations: 28146)



ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Tag(#70111841352580) expected, got #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x00007f8861ca8410 @columns=["id"], @rows=[[12]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={"id"=>#<ActiveModel::Type::Integer:0x00007f885e5608e0 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=8, @range=-9223372036854775808...9223372036854775808>}> which is an instance of ActiveRecord::Result(#70111841508420)):

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:40:in `block in create'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:31:in `each'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:31:in `create'
```

The relevant lines involve `upsert` and `create`:

```rb
# projects_controller.rb
...
def create
   @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      params[:tags].each do |tag|
         @tag = Tag.upsert({
                            category: 'topic',
                            name: tag
                          })
        ProjectTag.create(tag: @tag, project: @project)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: { "message": "success!", status: :ok } }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: { "errors": "Missing entries." } }
      end
    end
end
...
```

This is the fetch request launched on form submission:

```js
fetch(`../projects/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'X-Transaction': 'POST Example',
              'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
              'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']").content, // $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({project: project, tags: tags}),
            credentials: 'include'
          })
          .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw response;
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(data => {
            if (data.errors) {
              alert(`${data.errors}`);
            } else {
              console.log('Success:', data);
              alert('Saved.');
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            alert('error', data.errors);
          });
```

The tag model looks as such:

```rb
# tag.rb
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_tags
  has_many :issue_tags

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

---

**Update in response to max**

```
Started POST "/projects/" for ::1 at 2021-01-04 00:42:41 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"project"=>{"name"=>"Project 7", "tags_attributes"=>[{"name"=>"career_planning", "category"=>"topic"}, {"name"=>"angular", "category"=>"topic"}], "language"=>"Angular", "slogan"=>"xyz", "target"=>nil, "pain"=>nil, "solution"=>nil, "originality"=>nil, "vision"=>nil, "db_design_url"=>nil, "repo_url"=>nil, "proto_url"=>nil}, "tags"=>["career_planning", "angular"]}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  Tag Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "career_planning"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  Tag Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "angular"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  Project Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Project 7"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in create'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in create'
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms | Allocations: 9221)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails if you want to create a record and nested records in the same request [you use nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end
```

This will let you create a project and tags by simply passing an array of attributes:

```
Project.new(
  name: 'Learn Nested Attributes',
  tags_attributes: [
    { name: 'Ruby' },
    { name: 'Ruby On Rails' }
  ]
)
```

Then when you insert the parent it will efficiently create a single insert query instead of a n+1 query issue and it also lets you handle validation errors in the nested records in a sane way. You can use the `reject_if:` option or customize the setter to deal with existing records.

Your controller should simply look like:

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)   
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do 
      # Check if the record is actually persisted! Not just `.valid?`
      if @project.save
        # You should return meaningful response codes instead of 
        # just using the "json messages" anti-pattern
        render json: { "message": "success!" }, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: { "errors": "Missing entries." }, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end

private

def project_params
  params.require(:project)
        .permit(:foo, :bar, tags_attributes: [:name] )
end
```

In Rails your controllers are not the place for complexity as they are hard to test.

**However** nested attributes are not actually the best solution UX wise. If you instead create a separate endpoint to create tags and send separate AJAX requests you can provide direct user feedback as the user enters the tag name either autocompleting existing tags or providing direct validation feedback if the tag is not valid.

```
resources :tags, only: [:index, :create]
```

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /tags
  # GET /tags?search=foobarbaz
  def index
    @tags = if params[:search].present? 
        Tag.where('tags.name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
      else
        Tag.all
      end
    end
    render json: @tags
  end

  # POST /tags
  def create
    @tag = Tag.new(tag_params)
    if @tag.save
      render json: @tag, 
             status: :created
    else
      render json: { errors: @tag.errors.full_messages }, 
             status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
  def tag_params
    params.require(:tag)
          .permit(:name)
  end
end
```

You can then write a AJAX handler* that sends requests to `/tags?search=foobarbaz` to autocomplete and creates tags on the fly by sending requests to `POST /tags`. The controller will return the id of the newly created tag in the response body and you can use a form element in the form such as checkboxes or a select to store the tag ids or a set of hidden inputs (or custom elements / components).

The rails mechanism for assigning existing records is extremely simple. Just pass an array to the `_ids=` setter:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project)
        .permit(:foo, :bar, tag_ids: [])
end
```

Comment: That's incredibly helpful, thank you. I've attempted to use nested attributes, however nothing is saved now (neither the project nor the tags). The server log shows a ROLLBACK (see above).

Comment: I'm not really gonna try to help you salvage that - I don't really think that code is fixable as you haven't addressed issues like how to deal with invalid tags or dealing with failures to insert the tag or join row. The whole approach is just wrong. If you want to create multiple records like that you need to think about things like transactions and its actually quite a bit harder then you're imagining.

Comment: I'm thinking there's gotta be an easier way to create a simple form that saves to two different tables. Would you have an article that would steer me into the right direction?